# Removal of comma in the end of a string android

Tags: android

i have problem how to , remove the comma in the of my output. I use replaceall but it doesnt remove the comma , this my code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            String space = "";
            String foo = " ";
            String foo1 = ",";
            String sentences = null;

            //Splitting the sentence into words
            sentences = multiple.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
            String[] splitwords = sentences.trim().split("\\s+");

            for (String biyak : splitwords) {
                foo = (foo + "'" + biyak + "'" + foo1);


                foo.replaceAll(",$", " ");//foo.replaceAll();
                wordtv.setText(foo);
```

My codes Output : 'Hello','world',
My desire output: 'Hello','world'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` instances are immutable. As a result, methods like `replaceAll()` do not modify the original string but instead return a modified copy of the string. So replace `foo.replaceAll(...)` with `foo = foo.replaceAll(...)`.

Comment: Anyone know why replaceAll doesn't exist for strings?

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring method of String class. or You can use deleteCharAt() method of  StringBuilder or StringBuffer class
`StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(your_string);sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);`

Comment: I want to know what is the problem of code why it doesnt work?

Comment: foo.replaceAll(",", " ");//it will replace , by space and foo.replaceAll("$", "");//it will replace $ by space character

Comment: but i thought usng $ will remove the comma in the end?

Answer (score 0):

U can also use a if statement and traverse the whole string .
If a comma(,) is found replace it with a space(" ").